# How to crop into a new document with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a very hughe psd file with lots of layers. I need a way to do like a "copy merged" feature but pasting the result with layers instead of a flatten image.

Or in order words like a crop but into a new document instead of croping the whole original psd.

EDIT: As many don't understand I will try to expand:

I only want a portion of the original psd. When you use **Rectangular Marquee tool** and select a portion of the psd, and then you click Edit -> **Copy Merged** , and then you click **New file** and paste  you get a flatten image. I want the same but instead of a flatten image, I want the original layers of that portion I selected using marquee tool.

If that possible? A similar workaround I found is using the marquee tool, then click on Crop document. But my psd is so hughe that take minutes to crop it, and then I have to undo steps to get the original psd back.

UPDATE 2: When I do crop I get tons of popups saying the following:
[image]
That's the reason I was wondering if there is a faster way.

I hope it's clear, Im not a designer guy.

Comment: File > Save as.. rename it something new.. then do whatever you want to it.

Comment: I am having trouble understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to make a duplicate of the psd? Do you want to place the psd in another type of file? Can you just crop the the file and save as a new name?

Comment: @AndrewH I updated my question. I hope it's better explained now.

Comment: Not *everything* can happen instantaneously. I don't see why waiting a few minutes for the crop to commit is an issue.

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer in the form of a workaround. But to be very clear, the answer to your question ("Is this possible the way I want?") is "No."

Comment: @Scott I can wait if there is no other option , that's why I did the question in first place. But image I have to repeat this 20 times per psd I get 1 hour lost just waiting. How nice would be a command that avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the very big PSD file
2. Select the crop tool
3. Adjust to taste
4. Apply crop (<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Double Click</kbd> inside the crop)
5. Save it as a new document so as to preserve the original (Just in case!)

**UPDATE**

Here is a different way of cropping, this may bypass the pop up question or may not:

1. Add a new blank layer on top of the layer stack (as if you don't have enough!) and target it
2. Select the area you want to crop to with the rectangular marquee tool
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection
4. Fill the selected area on the blank layer with a color, say red
5. Go to Image/Trim and choose the top left (or a suitable side) pixel color

This will "trim" the image to leave the selected area remaining. As I said, I am not sure if you will still see the pop up or not. Try and see, and please let us know if it worked or not.

Comment: Hi, this is what Im exactly trying to avoid, because hitting crop on that psd takes like 3 minutes and lots of clicking on a popup window asking all the time IF I want to keep layers because there is unknown data on the psd.

Comment: I am not sure what "unknown date on the psd" may be. The layers are either pixel layers, adjustment layers, or smart objects. What happens if you say "Yes" to the question?

Comment: It happens the same :( I just pasted the screenshot on the question. I think the psd was created with a newer version. In order to achieve my goal I have to keep pressing "Keep Layers" in that popup like 100 times for every crop. I will accept your answer anyway because you showed me a new method, sadly why I wanted seems to be imposible in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be solved by placing the PSD as a Smart Object into another Photoshop document.

- Crop your image with the Crop tool - do not flatten the image.
- Save your PSD file, probably best to create a new file name, although
  it might not be necessary if you are using a newer version of
  Photoshop with the non-destructive Crop Tool.
- Then in the other Photoshop document, click File > Place, select the
  PSD you want to import, click on the canvas to place it, hit the
  enter key.

Now the object will be placed as a Smart Object.

You can edit the Smart Object by double clicking it in the layers panel, this will open the PSD with all the layers intact, should you wish to edit it.